# Golang interface{} type misunderstanding

Tags: json, pointers, go, interface, unmarshalling

I got a bug in Go when using an `interface{}` as function parameter type, when given a non-pointer type, and using `json.Unmarshal` with it.

Because a piece of code is worth a thousand words, here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func test(i interface{}) {
    j := []byte(`{ "foo": "bar" }`)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", &i)
    json.Unmarshal(j, &i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
}

type Test struct {
    Foo string
}

func main() {
    test(Test{})
}
```

Which outputs:

```
main.Test
*interface {}
map[string]interface {}
```

`json.Unmarshal` turns my struct to a `map[string]interface{}` oO...

Little readings later explains some of it, `interface{}` is a type in itself, not some sort of typeless container, which explains the `*interface{}`, and the fact that `json.Unmarshal` could not get the initial type, and returned a `map[string]interface{}`..

From `Unmarshal` docs:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
>   these in the interface value:
>   [...]

And if I pass a pointer to the test function like so, it works:

```
func test(i interface{}) {
    j := []byte(`{ "foo": "bar" }`)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", &i)
    json.Unmarshal(j, i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func main() {
    test(&Test{})
}
```

Which outputs:

```
*main.Test
*interface {}
*main.Test
&{bar}
```

Cool, the data is unmarshalled and all, now in this second snippet I removed the `&` when calling `Unmarshal`. Because I have a `*Test` in `i`, no use for it.

So in all logic, if I put back the `&` to `i` when calling `Unmarshal` it should mess up with `i`'s type again. But no.

If I run:

```
func test(i interface{}) {
    j := []byte(`{ "foo": "bar" }`)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", &i)
    json.Unmarshal(j, &i)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func main() {
    test(&Test{})
}
```

Well it still works:

```
*main.Test
*interface {}
*main.Test
&{bar}
```

And now I'm out of google search queries.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to never use a pointer to an interface. There's almost never a need for one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The right scenario

`interface{}` is a wrapper for any value and of any type. An interface schematically wraps a `(value; type)` pair, a concrete value and its type. More details on this: [The Laws of Reflection #The representation of an interface](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.).

[`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) already takes the value of type `interface{}`:

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

So if you already have an `interface{}` value (the `i interface{}` parameter of the `test()` function), don't try to take its address, just pass it along as-is.

Also note that for any package to modify a value stored in an `interface{}`, you need to pass a pointer to it. So what should be in `i` is a pointer. So the right scenario is to pass `*Test` to `test()`, and inside `test()` pass `i` to `json.Unmarshal()` (without taking its address).

#### Explanation of other scenarios

When `i` contains `*Test` and you pass `&i`, it will work because the `json` package will simply dereference the `*interface{}` pointer, and finds an `interface{}` value, which wraps a `*Test` value. It's a pointer, so it's all good: unmarshals the JSON object into the pointed `Test` value.

When `i` contains `Test` and you pass `&i`, same thing goes as above: `*interface{}` is dereferenced, so it finds an `interface{}` which contains a non-pointer: `Test`. Since the `json` package can't unmarshal into a non-pointer value, it has to create a new value. And since the passed value to the `json.Unmarshal()` function is of type `*interface{}`, it tells the `json` package to unmarshal the data into a value of type `interface{}`. This means the `json` package is free to choose which type to use. And by default the `json` package unmarshals JSON objects into `map[string]interface{}` values, so that is what's created and used (and eventually put into the value pointed by the pointer you passed: `&i`).

#### All in all

All in all, avoid using pointers to interfaces. Instead "put" pointers into the interfaces (the interface value should wrap the pointer). When you already have an `interface{}` holding a pointer, just pass it along.

Comment: Thanks @icza for the good read, this will surely be useful to a bunch of us.

Comment: Just went through the docs you pointed to, and especially the passage aboute settability, I guess that's what prevents Unmarshal to use the value in the interface{} when given a non-pointer.

Comment: @vitaminwater Yes. The value in the interface is a copy. If you want the `json` package to unmarshal into a variable you pass, you have to pass its address - a pointer (which will also be passed as a value), but the `json` package will not modify the pointer but the _pointed_ value - which is your variable.

Comment: For anyone seeking full explanations: https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_9. thanks @icza