# Expected slice but got interface

Tags: sql, go, interface, slice

I'm using sqlx package to make my database queries. I'm trying to create a global `SELECT *` for all my models in my database package

```
func FindAll(model interface{}, table string, db *sqlx.DB) error {
    err := db.Select(&model, "SELECT * FROM "+table)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("FindAll: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And I'm using it like this

```
albums := []Album{}
err := database.FindAll(albums, "album", a.DB)
```

But I got this error : `expected slice but got interface`

I don't know how can I manage the first model parameter to make it works for any models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `FindAll()`, the `model` parameter is of `interface{}` type. You pass a value of `[]Album` to it. It already wraps a slice value.

`db.Select()` also expects an argument of interface type (the same `interace{}` type). And you have an interface value of exactly this type, just pass it as-is:

```
err := db.Select(model, "SELECT * FROM "+table)
```

Although note that in order for `db.Select()` to be able to modify it, it must be a pointer, so `model` should wrap a pointer to a slice, not "just" a slice. So call `FindAll()` like this:

```
err := database.FindAll(&albums, "album", a.DB)
```

When you pass a value of concrete type when an interface type is needed, it will be wrapped in an interface value.

When you pass an interface value, if it is of the same interface type, it will be passed as-is. If it's a different interface type, the concrete value stored in it will be wrapped (re-wrapped) in an interface value of the expected interface type.

When you pass `&model`, you're passing a value of `*interface{}`, a pointer to an interface type. That's **not** an interface type, it's a concrete type, so this concrete type will be wrapped in an interface value when passed.

See related question: [Golang interface{} type misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829941/golang-interface-type-misunderstanding/38830638#38830638)